# Add row at after certain intervals and copy data into it in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have sampling data per depth in a dataframe. Now the orginal depth has to be interpolated to a new depth, for which I have information in a different dataframe.
So what needs to happen is:

- create a new row after each sample type (i.e. a, b,)
- copy "value" from above
- take last sam_bot(bottom) as new sam_top
- take dat2 sam_new_bot as new sam_bot

The first data.frame looks like this:

```
dat1 = data.frame(Samp = rep(letters[1:4], each = 4), 
             sam_top = seq(1:4), 
             sam_bot = seq(2,5), 
             value = runif(16), 
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```

gives me:

```
   Samp sam_top sam_bot      value
1     a       1       2 0.75864637
2     a       2       3 0.44056410
3     a       3       4 0.18105700
4     a       4       5 0.67938119
5     b       1       2 0.75444497
6     b       2       3 0.59411439
7     b       3       4 0.11755459
8     b       4       5 0.70143005
9     c       1       2 0.44234565
10    c       2       3 0.82872824
```

and a second dataframe with new depths for the first one look like this:

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = "Samp sam_new_bot
a      6
b      7
c      6
d      7.5", header = TRUE)

> dat2
  Samp   sam_new_bot
1    a         6.0
2    b         7.0
3    c         6.0
4    d         7.5
```

And the result should look like this:

```
   Samp sam_top sam_bot      value
1     a       1       2 0.75864637
2     a       2       3 0.44056410
3     a       3       4 0.18105700
4     a       4       5 0.67938119
5     a       5       6 0.67938119
5     b       1       2 0.75444497
6     b       2       3 0.59411439
7     b       3       4 0.11755459
8     b       4       5 0.70143005
9     b       5       7 0.70143005
10    c       1       2 0.44234565
```

Note that the data.frame has no fixed intervals, so there could be any number of Samp after each other.

**Update:**
I manage to insert the rows with:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dat1, dat1$Samp, rbind, dat1[1,]))
```

Now my understanding is, that I have to replace the dat1[1] part with a function of x, but somehow I don't get things together.

Comment: Both solutions below work, though I would appreciate a solution that does not include to sort or order the file. The original datasets contains a quite a lot of columns that sometimes depend on a different order than sam_top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your definitions of `dat1` and `dat2`:

```
dat3 <- with(dat2,data.frame(Samp, sam_top=NA, sam_bot=sam_new_bot, value=NA))
dat3         <- dat3[dat3$Samp %in% dat1$Samp,]        # only use Samp in dat1
dat3$sam_top <- aggregate(sam_bot~Samp,dat1,tail,1)$sam_bot
dat3$value   <- aggregate(value~Samp,dat1,tail,1)$value
final        <- rbind(dat1,dat3)
final        <- final[order(final$Samp,final$sam_top),]
```

Produces:

```
final
#    Samp sam_top sam_bot     value
# 1     a       1       2 0.7586464
# 2     a       2       3 0.4405641
# 3     a       3       4 0.1810570
# 4     a       4       5 0.6793812
# 11    a       5       6 0.6793812
# 5     b       1       2 0.7544450
# 6     b       2       3 0.5941144
# 7     b       3       4 0.1175546
# 8     b       4       5 0.7014301
# 12    b       5       7 0.7014301
# 9     c       1       2 0.4423456
# 10    c       2       3 0.8287282
# 13    c       3       6 0.8287282
```

The row names are different, but hopefully that is not important.

This code creates a dataframe `dat3` with a template for the extra rows based on your `dat2`, then sets `sam_top` and `value` in the template based on your criteria, then adds those rows to your original `dat1`, to create `final`, then reorders final to match your result. Note the use of the `tail(...)` function in `aggregate(...)` to extract the last row in a series.

Finally, your `dat2` has a `Samp="d"`, whereas your `dat1` does not; this is the reason for the second line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`.  Logic is as follows:

1. get the max `sam_top` for every `Samp`, as well as the corresponding value
2. merge this to `dat2` to get the new `sam_bot` for each of the new `sam_top`
3. rbind back to `dat1`

The answer doesn't look exactly the same as your as the data is different (I used your data creation code though):

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(dat1)
dat1.sub <- dat1[  # get new sam_top, as well as last value for Samp
  order(sam_top), 
  list(sam_top=max(sam_bot), value=tail(value, 1L)), 
  by=Samp
]
dat2.sub <- merge(dat1.sub, dat2, by="Samp")[, c(1, 2, 4, 3), with=F] # match to `dat2`
rbind(dat1, unname(as.list(dat2.sub)))[order(Samp, sam_top)]  # now rbind back and order
#     Samp sam_top sam_bot      value
# 1:     a       1       2 0.37475446
# 2:     a       2       3 0.87263241
# 3:     a       3       4 0.53154291
# 4:     a       4       5 0.41648329
# 5:     a       5       6 0.41648329
# 6:     b       1       2 0.36251215
# 7:     b       2       3 0.33083137
# 8:     b       3       4 0.03237498
# 9:     b       4       5 0.75553453
# 10:    b       5       7 0.75553453
# 11:    c       1       2 0.98819386
# 12:    c       2       3 0.95251107
# 13:    c       3       4 0.35680588
# 14:    c       4       5 0.34674393
# 15:    c       5       6 0.34674393
# 16:    d       1       2 0.19573338
# 17:    d       2       3 0.59690127
# 18:    d       3       4 0.87038993
# 19:    d       4       5 0.88751762
# 20:    d       5       7 0.88751762
```